# How can i Show a alert and confirm Before deleting a data value from mysql in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a alert box after user presses the delete button if he press ok after that the row should be deleted. i tried to use alert in my app.js file but it is showing alert is not defined. does this have any solution.

Comment: I think you're trying to use a browser's `alert()` function in a server-side node.js application.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Could you show your code ? In general, for debugging questions, the relevant code is expected, this often clarifies the problem a lot, and allows for quicker and more precise answers. See also [mcve], and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. User press Delete
2. Show popup with Ok/Cancel

   ```
   <div>
       Do you want to delete?
       <div id="ok-button">OK</div>
       <div>Cancel</div>
    </div>
   ```

`<script>
       $("#ok-button").on("click",function(){
          $.ajax({
             url: my_url,
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {id : "id_to_delete"},
             contentType: "application/json"
          }).done(function(notification_from_server) 
             {alert(notification_from_server);});
       });
    </script>`

3. If user press Ok, do ajax call to server that do DB things
4. Ajax call have call back for showing "Item has been deleted" notification when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

node.js is backend (server side) javascript and alert is supported in UI javascript. you can use console.log(data) in node.js to check result in node.js.